# Tweepy with Django

Tags: python, django

I’m confused on how to make this work. I want to stream user’s tweets in my django app using tweepy. I’ve written the streaming code but the problem I’m facing is: should I paste the code in views.py and input-

```
       return render_to_response('tweet.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

after writing the code. Just like this:

```
             import sys
             import tweepy
            import webbrowser
            import MySQLdb


           Q= sys.argv[1:]

          db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","","","Juzme")

          auth=tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
          auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

           cur=db.cursor()

               class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
                                 def on_status(self, status):
                         try:
                            print "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s" % (status.text,
                                  status.author.screen_name,
                                  status.created_at,
                                  status.source,)
             cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweets VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)", (status.text,
                                                                        status.author.screen_name,
                                                                   status.created_at,
                                                                   status.source))
              except Exception, e:
                  print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered Exception:', e
                  pass
             def on_error(self, status_code):
             print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
             return True

             def on_timeout(self):
             print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
             return True
     streaming_api=tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener(), timeout=60)
     print >> sys.stderr, 'Filtering the public timeline for "%s"' % ('  '.join(sys.argv[1:]),)
     streaming_api.filter(follow=[], track=Q)
     return render_to_response('tweet.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If I can do it like this, won’t there be any code in template? Or what’s the best way I can carry out this operation. I hope you get my point? Thanks

Comment: Sorry how do I accept answers?

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: Also, use Django models instead of direct DB queries. And describe what are you getting and what do you want to get?